# Azure Data Factory CI/CD for Schedule Triggers Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

For triggers it looks like only `pipelines` `pipeline` and `typeProperties` blocks can be overriden based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#default-parameterization-template).

What I want to achieve is with my CI/CD process and overriding parameters [functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#use-custom-parameters-with-the-resource-manager-template), to have a schedule trigger disabled in the target ADF, unlike my source ADF.

If I inspect the JSON of a trigger that looks like the following field could do the trick `"runtimeState": "Started"`.

```
{
    "name": "name_daily",
    "properties": {
        "description": " ",
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "name",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2020-05-05T13:01:00.000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        13
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I attempt to add it in the JSON file like this:

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers": {
        "properties": {
            "runtimeState": "-",
            "typeProperties": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "interval": "=",
                    "frequency": "="
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it never shows up in the Override section in Azure Pipeline Releases.

Does this ADF CI/CD functionality exist for triggers? How can I achieve my target here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `runtimeState` for triggers is not obeyed in the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json`.

The path is clearer after some more research - I can achieve what I want with either editing the [Powershell script Microsoft has provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#script) or use an [ADF custom task](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53153.azuredevops-cicd-for-azure-data-factory.aspx#Starting_all_the_triggers) from the Azure Devops marketplace.